# Android ListView with two columns that only takes up bottom part of the screen

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add a listview on the bottom of my opening activity that has two text items. Anyone know how to do this? I see stuff on how to do a listview with two columns, and how to do a listview at the bottom of an activity, but I can't find any that does both.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my sample. It displays ImageView and TextView but two TextViews are absolutely the same. ListView takes top part in my sample but you can just move it to the bottom. [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)